# while exporting data from SQL Server using Export-Csv (PowerShell) command double quotes are converted into question mark (?)

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Here is my Table having column "Value"-

| Value |
| --- |
| This "data"). has consists of "information" |
| ("Party A") and ("Party B") |

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'SQLSERVER' -Database "SQL" -Query "select * from Table" | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Desktop\Outquery.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

this code works fine but while exporting the data into CSV file doublequotes are converted into unexpected value with question mark (?)

CSV OUTPUT:-

```
   VALUE
  -------    
 This ?data?). has consists of ?information?
 (?Party A?) and (?Party B?)
```

Comment: Start debugging by running the query and print it on console. Are the quotes already missing?

Comment: After further research  have added "-Encoding UTF8" at the end of the code it is now exporting as expected.

Comment: Based on your last comment I'm assuming you're using a version of PowerShell earlier than PowerShell 6. PowerShell 6 and later use a default text encoding of UTF8, whereas earlier versions use Windows Codepage 1252 (aka. iso-8859-1). The quotes in the SQL data probably weren't US-ASCII quote characters (U+0022) but one of the stylistic typography quotes like U+201C, U+201D or U+2033, and so couldn't be written to an iso-8859-1 encoded file correctly.

Comment: yes you are right. this issue is only with older version.

Answer (score 0):

After further research adding "-Encoding UTF8" at the end of the code it is now exporting as expected.